# How to call controller function from html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi I am very new to AngularJs and to HTML, Javascript and CSS so please try to explain your answers for dummys.

So, for some reason the function "updateFilterTerm" does not get called. The variable "filterTerm" always remains the same as initialized.

Like you see in the code the page that is calling the function is another one like the page that is displaying the content with the help of the variable "filterTerm" but they have the same controller "BatchMonitorCtrl".

Do I do anything wrong or can you guide me to the solution to this problem?

Here is part of my Controller.js:

```
...
function BatchMonitorCtrl($scope, Batchmonitor, BatchmonitorConfig, ConfigService, $localStorage, $timeout, flash, $routeParams) {
    $scope.filterTerm = '2312ab78-1e3c-48c5-82af-e38b42d704eb';

    $scope.updateFilterTerm = function(filterTerm) {
        $scope.filterTerm = filterTerm;
    };
}
...
```

And here is part of my bm.html:

```
...
<span ng-switch-default
    class="label label-primary {{types[charge.Type].CSS}}"
    style="cursor:pointer;padding:8px;"
    onclick="$(this).popover('toggle')"
    data-html='true'
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-trigger="manual"
    data-placement="top"
    title="{{&quot;common.BatchStatus-OK&quot;|i18n}}"
    data-content="Type: {{charge.Type}}<br />LogicalId: {{charge.LogicalId}}<br />Nest: {{charge.Nests}}<br />SetupDate: {{ charge.SetupDateObject | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}<br/>Updated: {{ charge.Updated['$date'] | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}
    <br/><br/><a href='#/delete-charge' class='btn btn-primary btn-block' ng-click='updateFilterTerm({{charge._id}})'><span>{{&quot;common.Delete-Charge&quot;|i18n}}</span></a>">
    <h5><strong>{{charge.LogicalId}}</strong></h5>
</span>
...
```

And here is part of my dc.html where I use "filterTerm" to filter the batches:

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="batch in allBatches | orderBy: 'Sort' | filter: filterTerm">
...
```

Comment: Just to be clear. The filter with the variable "filterTerm" works. The problem is that the function does not set "$scope.filterTerm = filterTerm;".

Comment: Maybe the syntax in "data-content" is wrong? Because of the String I am not sure if it gets resolved correctly at this point:  

     data-content="...ng-click='updateFilterTerm({{charge._id}})'..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a answer to my own question.

As I have the same controller on both partials (pages) they have both their own instance of this controller. So even if the function is called the next page will not have the information from the previous page. So I will need to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not sure, but I think it related to scope inheritance.
Try to use controllerAs syntax, or other dot access technics:

```
| filter : obj.filterTerm;

function setFilter(term){
    $scope.obj.filterTerm = term;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work for me. Maybe I didn't understand it correctly. Also see my comments to my question.

Answer (score 0):

In your Html View please use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function functiontocallcontrollermethod()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Poll/Mymethod',
        data: { voteid: $("#voteDemocrat").val() }
    });

</script>
```

In your controller

```
  [HttpPost]
  [WebMethod]

      public void Mymethod(int voteid)
    {

        /// WORK HERE
    }
```

Finally WebMethod namespace is

using System.Web.Services;